# Can a microwave motor be powered by usb?

Tags: usb, motor, microwave

Firstly, I'm not even a beginner. I'd need extensive training to become a novice!! My problem, I'm trying to build a rotating display for some decorative coins. I initially thought of servo motors and YouTubed how to connect one to a usb cable but then I heard that they "click" and I want a silent motion. A friend suggested microwave motors but wasn't sure if a 5v usb would actually be "man enough" to operate one. Can anyone tell me if it is possible, please?

Comment: Microwave oven turntable synchronous motors run from mains AC, they will not work from a USB supply at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microwave motors that I have seen are AC motors. There are very small motors with attached gears that might be suitable. They are sold for hobby and educational use.

Most of the power is lost in the motor and gear. The electrical input power will probably be more that twice the mechanical output power. A 5 volt USB supply may or may not be able to supply enough current. You will need to look at what is available. Sellers of inexpensive motors often don't supply clear information about the current required. Sometimes they just state free-running (no load) current and stall current. For a gear motor with the speed you need, the safe continuous current will probably be 2 or 3 times the no-load current.

If the load is too much for the motor, it will run slow, draw too much current and overheat. The stall current will be quite a bit higher. The power supply will need to supply the stall current for a fraction of a second when the motor is turned on. That could cause a "smart" power supply to switch off.

Answer (score 0):

A microwave motor would probably require more tinkering than at first appears, if it could be made to work at all.

If you do a google search for "DC gearmotor 5v" you'll find hundreds of much more suitable options, perhaps such as [this one](https://www.allelectronics.com/item/dcm-416/85-rpm-12-vdc-gear-motor/1.html).

Answer (score 0):

USB power is really quite limited. As well as motors made for your particular application, if you can go to 12 volts you could look at the motors used for rotating reflectors on automobile warning beacons or disco lights.

However, USB powered turntables for light loads are available quite cheaply. (Example [Amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ljourney-Turntable-Photography-Automatic-Collectibles/dp/B07QYYTGJ2/))